# Why "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" showing

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am developing a project in `javafx` using `NetBeans IDE`. Whenever I run my code I am getting some exceptions. There was no problems till yesterday. The exceptions are given below :

```
Executing E:\Project\WelcomePage\dist\run204992192\WelcomePage.jar using platform       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:698)
at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:871)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class welcomepage.WelcomePage
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:393)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: welcomepage.WelcomePage.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1718)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:275)
    ... 3 more
    Java Result: 1
```

My source code is very large, so I excluded the import statements. I will provide a part of my code below:

```
 class WelcomePage extends Application {
 @Override
 public void start(Stage stage33) {

    BorderPane border = new BorderPane();

    border.setTop(addVBox());
    border.setLeft(addVBox1());

    Scene scene = new Scene(border,700,450);
    stage33.setScene(scene);
    stage33.setResizable(false);
    scene.getStylesheets().add
    (WelcomePage.class.getResource("WelcomePage.css").toExternalForm());
    stage33.show();

 }

 private VBox addVBox() {

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 12, 5, 20));
    vbox.setSpacing(10);   // Gap between nodes
    //vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #999999;");

    Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("logo11.png"));
    Label lb1=new Label("    C - MARK AND ATTENDANCE CALCULATOR");
    lb1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    lb1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,28));
    lb1.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
    lb1.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));

    vbox.getChildren().addAll(lb1);

    return vbox;
 }

 private VBox addVBox1()
 {
    VBox vbox1=new VBox();
    vbox1.setPadding(new Insets(20, 2, 15, 20));
    vbox1.setSpacing(20);

    Button btnl2=new Button("SIGN IN");
    btnl2.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
    btnl2.setPrefSize(300,60);
    btnl2.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066cc;");

    btnl2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
       signin();
     }
     });

    Button btnl4=new Button("HELP");
    btnl4.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
    btnl4.setPrefSize(300,60);
    btnl4.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066cc;");

    btnl4.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
      help();
     }
     });

    Button btnl5=new Button("ABOUT");
    btnl5.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
    btnl5.setPrefSize(300,60);
    btnl5.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066cc;");

    btnl5.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
      about();
     }
     });

    Button btnl6=new Button("EXIT");
    btnl6.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
    btnl6.setPrefSize(300,60);
    btnl6.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066cc;");

    btnl6.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
      System.exit(0);
     }
     });

    vbox1.getChildren().addAll(btnl2,btnl4,btnl5,btnl6);

    return vbox1;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Is that your whole class? Maybe try to make it public?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@assylias, from the comments, is correct. Your class implicitly has package visibility, since you haven't provided an access modifier. The Java Language Specification says

> the default constructor has the default access implied by no access modifier.

So your default no-arg constructor given by the compiler has default access.

The [`Class#getConstructor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) method which [`com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/application/LauncherImpl.java#LauncherImpl.launchApplication1%28java.lang.Class,java.lang.Class,java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) uses

> Returns a Constructor object that reflects the specified public
>   constructor of the class represented by this Class object.

But the constructor isn't `public` and therefore isn't visible to the `getConstructor(..)` method. So you get

> NoSuchMethodException - if a matching method is not found.

Provide a `public` constructor yourself or make your class `public`.